# jQuery dictionary alphabet filter to SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, filter, alphabetical

I have a list in SP2013 which I am pulling the list items using Javascript on a publishing page. I need to apply alphabetic filtering to this list, but the filter doesn't functioning on this list; however, the filter works perfectly on plain static text. Here is my code to pull the list items:

```
    $(function () {
        if (glossaryQuery && glossaryQuery.Rows) {
        var liGlossaryHTML = [];
        $('#glossary_list').toggle();
        $.each(glossaryQuery.Rows, function (index, r) {
            liGlossaryHTML.push('<li><strong>' + r.Title + '</strong><br/>' + r.Definition + '</li>');
        });            
        $('#glossary_list ul').html(liGlossaryHTML.join(''));
    }
});
```

and here is the filter:

```
   var triggers = $('ul.alphabet li a');
    var filters = $('#glossary_list ul li');

    triggers.click(function() {
    var takeLetter = $(this).text(), result = 0;
    filters.parent().hide();

filters.each(function(i) {
    if ( RegExp('^'+takeLetter).test($(this).text()) ) {
        result += 1;
        $(this).parent().fadeIn(222);
    }
});
```

});

and the HTML:

```
<div id="glossary_list" style="display:none;">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

Any help is so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that because you're adding the list items after page load that `filters` doesn't actually match anything at the time that it is run. I suggest moving the assignment inside the click handler. There are some other improvements you could make to make it more efficient/readable as well.

```
$('ul.alphabet li a').click(function() {
    var takeLetter = $(this).text(),
        result = 0
        expr = new RegExp('^' + takeLetter);

    var filters = $('#glossary_list ul li')
        .parent()
        .hide();

    filters.each(function(i) {
         var $filter = $(this);
         if (expr.test($filter.text())) {
             result += 1;
             $filter.parent().fadeIn(222);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! your suggestion resolved the issue! much appreciated.